# Dynamic styling of data layer (icons) in Google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps-api

I want to use different icons based on attibute values 'art' in a Google Maps data.layer. I've defined an customIcons object with all the styling options I need.

```
var customIcons = {
    Ap: {
        icon: './images/pin_green.png'
    },
    Bi: {
        icon: './images/pin_yellow.png'
    },
    Wa: {
        icon: './images/pin_brown.png'
    }
};
```

When I try to use this object in a style function, I get an error: "a.url.substr is not a function"

```
   map.data.setStyle( function(feature){
    var art = feature.getProperty('art');
    var icons = customIcons[art] || {};
      return  { 
        icon: icons
      }
   });
```

When I use a single icon, passing the url like

```
icon: {url: './images/pin_green.png'}
```

it works, but all points use the same icon.
I've tried already a lot, but I cannot get the right syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change the return statement, now it works:

```
   map.data.setStyle( function(feature){
    var art = feature.getProperty('art');
    var icons = customIcons[art] || {};
      return  { 
        icon: icons.icon
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back to the question and adding the solution you found! This solved my problem and it's the only reference to it online that I've found :)